# Igor Pro, how to convert one text value in a wave to a string

Tags: igor

This is for Igor Pro, wavemetrics.

As part of a bigger task I'm trying to complete, I need to take a specific value from a text wave (e.g. wave[i]) and turn it into a string. How can I do this in Igor? My  next step is to use FindValue, and for a text wave I need to provide the exact string to look for. But I want it to go through a text wave one index at a time and look to see if that text is already included in a separate wave. If not, I want it to add that text. If it is, I want the for loop to move to the next index. This seems easy, but I've been struggling all morning!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a textwave with 100 points.
First, declare the wave as a textwave (/T flag) and then assign the value to the string inside the loop.

```
Wave/T myTextWave
String myString

for(i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
    myString = myTextWave[i]
    // do what you want here
    FindValue //(...)
endfor
```